# Is there a way to set the sliding duration for a range input?

Tags: html, css

I have an range type input for which I'd like to able to set the sliding duration to be 2s.

```
<input value="0" id="film-range" type="range" min="0" max="100"  step="25">
```

I've tried the following but it does not seem to work

```
#film-range {
animation-name: slide;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-iteration-count: 1;                              
}
```

Comment: you mean 2s while moving from 0 to 100?

Comment: 2s to slide to any step